# Получить значение из кастомизированного библиотекой чекбокса и отправить в форме

Tags: javascript, html, css

Решил облагородить свою форму такого рода чекбоксами

https://www.codehim.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-toggle-switch-with-text/
Все работает, НО как мне теперь получить состояние элемента, оформление основано на кнопках ? Форма улетает пустой.

Comment: Не понятно как у вас до этого происходила отправка формы, наверное форма обрабатывалась на сервере после чего вся информация отправлялась на хранение в базу данных

Comment: Я делаю новую форму, прежде использовал в связке с Input, тут "купился" на оформление. Решение найдено

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот чтобы использовать как написано в документации - по-моему, если только js-ом получать наличие/отсутствие класса `active` и добавлять в форму.

Сам по себе этот кастомный чекбокс, даже если настроить как `label+checkbox`, не позволяет чекбоксы переключать чтобы передавать в форму.

А вот если отказаться от `bootstrap.min.js` и написать свой обработчик добавления класса active - можно немного упростить задачу. Приблизительно как в коде ниже. Чтобы проверить работу чекбокса - достаточно в последней строчке стилей временно закомментировать `display: none`

И, да в bootsrap есть такие же переключатели [switches](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/#switches) сразу с чекбоксами, которые с небольшой доработкой стилей возможно вам подойдут.

```js
document.querySelector('.btn').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.classList.toggle('active');
})
```

```css
.btn-toggle {
  margin: 0 4rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle:focus,
.btn-toggle.focus,
.btn-toggle:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 4rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -4rem;
}

.btn-toggle:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -4rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.active:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle:before,
.btn-toggle:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.active {
  background-color: #29b5a8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg {
  margin: 0 5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  border-radius: 2.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  line-height: 2.5rem;
  width: 5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -5rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.3125rem;
  left: 0.3125rem;
  width: 1.875rem;
  height: 1.875rem;
  border-radius: 1.875rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active>.handle {
  left: 2.8125rem;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  left: 0.6875rem;
  width: 3.875rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-lg.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm {
  margin: 0 0.5rem;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1.5rem;
  width: 3rem;
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: 1.5rem;
  width: 0.5rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.55rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: -0.5rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: -0.5rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.1875rem;
  left: 0.1875rem;
  width: 1.125rem;
  height: 1.125rem;
  border-radius: 1.125rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active>.handle {
  left: 1.6875rem;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -0.5rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  left: 0.4125rem;
  width: 2.325rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-sm.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
  height: 1rem;
  width: 2rem;
  border-radius: 1rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:focus.active,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.focus.active {
  outline: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  line-height: 1rem;
  width: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 0.75rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:before {
  content: 'Off';
  left: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs:after {
  content: 'On';
  right: 0;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs>.handle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0.125rem;
  left: 0.125rem;
  width: 0.75rem;
  height: 0.75rem;
  border-radius: 0.75rem;
  background: #fff;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active {
  transition: background-color 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active>.handle {
  left: 1.125rem;
  transition: left 0.25s;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  line-height: -1rem;
  color: #fff;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  left: 0.275rem;
  width: 1.55rem;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:before {
  text-align: right;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm:after {
  text-align: left;
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:before {
  opacity: 0;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-sm.active:after {
  opacity: 1;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-xs.btn-xs:after {
  display: none;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary {
  color: #6b7381;
  background: #bdc1c8;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:before,
.btn-toggle.btn-secondary:after {
  color: #6b7381;
}

.btn-toggle.btn-secondary.active {
  background-color: #ff8300;
}

.btn span {
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css'>

<label class="btn btn-lg btn-toggle" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="true" autocomplete="off">
<div class="handle"><input type="checkbox" value="1" ></div>

</label>
```